# Comparing two email addresses in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
EG:
table 1: Email Address
         user1@abc.com
         user25@abc.com
         user35@abc.com

table 2: Email Addresses in DB
         user12@abc.com
         user25@abc.com
         user35@abc.com
         user@67@abc.com
         user111@xyz.com

O/p: table

    Email Address reported    | Match/No match |
         user1@abc.com       |NO  match in DB
        user25@abc.com       | match in DB
         user35@abc.com      |match in DB
```

Please share complete SQL query, where I can compare which email addresses matches in DB.enter code here

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that this is not a coding (or homework) service. Show what you have tried so far and what errors you encounter and you should get some help with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO output_table
    SELECT email
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.email = table2.email
```

Of course, you will need to adjust the code for your table names and column names.

You can read more about inner join here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmailAddress,
CASE
    WHEN EmailAddress in (select EmailAddress from table2)  THEN 'match in DB'
    ELSE 'NO  match in DB'
END AS 'Match/No match'
FROM table1
```

Comment: For your information: Usually people provide explanations of the code they post in their answers, but in this case the OP asked for code only, which you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking to check whether each email in `table1` exists in `table2`. You can use a `left join`:

```
select 
    t1.email, 
    case when t2.email is not null then 'match' else 'no match' end as `match/no_match`
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.email = t2.email
```

If there is a possibility that a given email may appear more than once in `table2`, then you can use a correlated subquery with an `exists` condition:

```
select 
    t1.email, 
    case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.email = t1.email) 
        then 'match' 
        else 'no match' 
    end as `match/no_match`
from table1 t1
```

Comment: Thanks the first query works, but yes I am getting duplicates email address count, How shall I use the subquery, will it be with left join. Please explain and give me the query.

Comment: @S.Y.K.J: if you get duplicates with the first query, you can use the second query instead. Please give it a try.

Comment: I get error when I use the second query. please explain and give the query